# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token - due to double backslash

Tags: json

I seem to have a strange problem, I get a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token P" error. It is due to the double backslash. But double backslash is need to escape a backslash and this seems to be 100% valid JSON which is generated from php's json_encode function.

```
var urls = '{"MyApp\\Posts\\Post":"foo","MyApp\\Threads\\Thread":"bar"}';
obj = jQuery.parseJSON(urls);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you `console.log(urls)`, you can see the string value that is passed to the JSON parser:

```
{"MyApp\Posts\Post":"foo","MyApp\Threads\Thread":"bar"}
```

However, `\` is the escape character in JSON and `\P` is an invalid escape sequence.

---

"The problem" is that backslash is also the escape character in a JS string. If you want to produce a literal backslash in a JS string for JSON, you have  to double escape it:

```
var urls = '{"MyApp\\\\Posts\\\\Post":"foo","MyApp\\\\Threads\\\\Thread":"bar"}';
```

That said, there is no value in having a string literal with JSON in JS. You can just use an object literal:

```
var urls = {"MyApp\\Posts\\Post":"foo","MyApp\\Threads\\Thread":"bar"};
```

---

**Note:** If the JSON *is not* in a string literal, but you get it as response from an Ajax call, for example, then

```
{"MyApp\\Posts\\Post":"foo","MyApp\\Threads\\Thread":"bar"}'
```

is valid JSON.